# SQL DELIMITER error while executing Trigger

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, orm, mariadb

I have created the following trigger :

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_order_replica
//
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_order_replica AFTER INSERT ON order_replica
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO exm_order 
       (replica_id)
     VALUES (NEW.id);
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I tried to execute it from PHP it showed me the following errors :

> Error performing query 'DELIMITER // DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_order_replica; ': You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS
>   after_insert_order_replica' at line 1
>
> Error performing query '// CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_order_replica
>   AFTER INSERT ON res_order_replica FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO
>   res_order ( replica_id ) VALUES ( NEW.id); ': You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '// CREATE TRIGGER
>   after_insert_order_replica AFTER INSERT ON res_order_replica ' at line
>   1
>
> Error performing query 'END; ': You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
>
> Error performing query ' // DELIMITER ;': You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '// DELIMITER' at line 1

I tried with different DELIMITER but no luck.

here is my PHP code

```
public function Triggers(){

    $restaurants = $this->em->getRepository('entities\company')->findBy(
        array("companyName" => "testing_trigger")
    );


        set_time_limit(0);

        include APPPATH . 'config/database.php';
        $data = array();
        $sql = "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'basedir'";
        $result = $this->common->runSQL($sql);
        $data['folderPath'] = rtrim(rtrim($result[0]['Value'], "/"), "\\");
        $data['folderPath'] .= "/bin";

        foreach ($restaurants as $rts) {    

          $data['dbHost'] = $rts->getServer()->getDbHost();
          $data['dbUsername'] = $rts->getServer()->getDbUsername();
          $data['dbPassword'] = $rts->getServer()->getDbPassword();
          $data['dbDatabase'] = $rts->getDbDatabase();


          $triggerAry = array(
         "After Insert Order Replica"  => "after_insert_order_replica.txt"
          );

         foreach ($triggerAry as $k=>$v) {
           $trigger = FCPATH . "assets/$v";
            $this->IMPORT_TABLES($data['dbHost'],$data['dbUsername'],$data['dbPassword'],$data['dbDatabase'], $trigger);


             usleep(100000); //1 of 10th of a Second

        }
     }
}


function IMPORT_TABLES($host,$user,$pass,$dbname, $sql_file_OR_content){
set_time_limit(3000);
$SQL_CONTENT = (strlen($sql_file_OR_content) > 300 ?  $sql_file_OR_content : file_get_contents($sql_file_OR_content)  );  
$allLines = explode("\n",$SQL_CONTENT); 
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname); if (mysqli_connect_errno()){echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();} 
$templine = ''; // Temporary variable, used to store current query
foreach ($allLines as $line)    {                                           // Loop through each line
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) != '--' && $line != '') {$templine .= $line;    // (if it is not a comment..) Add this line to the current segment
        if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {        // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
            if(!$mysqli->query($templine)){ print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . $mysqli->error . '<br /><br />');  }  $templine = ''; // set variable to empty, to start picking up the lines after ";"
        }
    }
}   return 'Importing finished. Now, Delete the import file.';
```

}

Comment: Remove `;` at the end of `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_insert_order_replica;`

Comment: I did..but its showing the same error

Comment: Are you trying to run it from PHP code, or in PHPMyAdmin ? If running using PHP code, edit the question to add your code details also

Comment: I tried to run it from PHP ...and I have added my PHP code

Answer (score 1):

I think the `DELIMITER` technique is just a trick for the commandline tool mysql.

Do the `DROP ...` as a query from PHP.  Then do the entire `CREATE ... END;` from PHP.  Don't use `DELIMITER` or `//` in either.

Comment: Thanks...I solved problem by using php's system() function

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is to delete the function called IMPORT_TABLES and use following PHP code:

```
$command = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -h ".$data['dbHost']." -u ".$data['dbUsername']." -p".$data['dbPassword']." ".$data['dbDatabase']." < ".$trigger;

system($command);
```